# Защита в ajax файлах от внешнего исполнения

Tags: php, ajax

Есть в админке системы ajax файлы, к примеру `sort.php` - при перетаскивании разделов срабатывает скрипт, который отправляет этому файлу новый порядок и этот файл пишет этот порядок в БД.

Как оптимально защитить подобные файлы от внешнего исполнения? К примеру, тот, у кого есть исходники, но нет доступа в админу может сделать так: `sort.php?div=1&sort=1,4,5,6,3` и изменить сортировку разделов.

Comment: повесить проверку "а кто это делает", хотя бы по id сессии (как минимум), дальше больше - проверить user-агента, ip (?), куки... скрытое поле в админке ( с пост запросом)....

Comment: С точки зрения сервера неважно, AJAX или не AJAX. Отличается только формат ответа: целая страница или какой-то фрагмент данных. Всё, что проверяется при рендере страниц, надо проверять и при ответах на асинхронки.

Answer (score 2):

В админке sort.php вы должны обрабатывать полученный запрос только в том случае, если запрос приходит от админа (модератора). Следовательно, в sort.php нужно проверять авторизован ли пользователь и является ли он админом. Аналогично тому, как это делается в вашей системе.

Можно было бы на nginx обрабатывать запросы, которые приходят только с определённых ip (allow ip; deny  all;). 
Но т.к. у вас уже сделана авторизация на других страницах, то проще и правильнее всего, на мой взгляд, проверять авторизован ли юзер во всех api-методах. Это было бы оптимально.

Answer (score 0):

возможно пора задуматься об [ACL](https://github.com/myclabs/ACL)

[вот тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/109713/) на хабре описывают как создать такое самому

Answer (score 0):

Выполняйте любое действие в админке только если юзер авторизован и является админом. В остальных же файлах админки у вас так и сделано?

Comment: Для админки отдельный модуль авторизации с пользователями и правами. Можно его подключить во всех ajax-скриптах и проверять. Это один способ. Если нет других - так и сделаю.